# How to control the line thickness/width in ScottPlot (within WPF)

Tags: scottplot

I'm using ScottPlot within a WPF app; specifically, I'm using `Plot.AddSignal()` to add my signals to a graph.

I see that the width of vertical or horizontal lines can be controlled by the width property, as follows:

`Plot.AddVerticalLine(x:10.0, width: 4f);`

But how can I control the thickness (width) of signals I add to the chart using `AddSignal()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SignalPlotBase<T>.LineWidth`](https://scottplot.net/doc/v4/api/ScottPlot.Plottable.SignalPlotBase-1.html#ScottPlot_Plottable_SignalPlotBase_1_LineWidth):

For example:

```cs
var sig = Plot.AddSignal(args);
sig.LineWidth = 4;
```